# This technology is very expensive (to use) to grow food. Is this correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

I know the following are correct:

> This technology is very expensive to use.
>
> This tool is very handy to use.

Are the following constructions correct? I don't know if we can add an infinitive phrase after them to indicate a purpose.

> 1, This technology is very expensive to use to grow food.
>
> 2, This tool is very handy to use to achieve that goal.

Are the following constructions correct? I think they are incorrect because the infinitive phrase doesn't match the subject. While *"use this technology, use this tool"* are correct, *"grow food this technology, achieve that goal this tool"* are incorrect.

> 3, This technology is very expensive to grow food.
>
> 4, This tool is very handy to achieve that goal.

Comment: "This technology is an expensive _way_ to grow food."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say:

> This technology is very expensive.
>
> This technology is very expensive **for growing food**.

You don't really achieve a goal with a tool -- it's too general. You should be more specific about how it's handy.

> This tool is very handy.
>
> This tool is very handy **for getting stripped screws out of their sockets**.

Answer (score 0):

No, they aren't correct for various reasons. We don't do proofreading or error-finding on this site (off-topic) but consider these reasons why they don't make sense.

The problem with your first example compared to the ones you later say you know to be correct is that it doesn't specify whether the technology is expensive as an outlay (ie the initial cost of the tech), or has expensive ongoing costs involved.

> This technology is very expensive to use.
> It is very expensive to use this technology to grow food.

Both of these refer to the *use* being expensive.

Your others involving courses are missing a preposition. You get a high mark *on*, or *in* a course / exam.

Comment: "A simple course is easier for students to get a high mark in." Does this work?

Comment: @joy2020 Yes that's fine.